# Spring JPA Hibernate : slow SELECT query

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I encounter an optimisation problem and I can't figure out why my query is so slow.

Here my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "CLIENT_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CLIENT_S", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
private Long id;

@Column(name="LOGIN")
private String login;

@Column(name="PASSWORD")
private String password;
```

And the DAO

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ClientDao extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Client> {
    Client findByPasswordAndLogin(@Param("login") String customerLogin,@Param("password") String customerHashedPassword);
}
```

When the method findByPasswordAndLogin is executed, it takes about 200ms to be completed (seen both through Junit tests and with JProfiler).

Here the Hibernate query :
    Hibernate: select clientx0_.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT_ID1_4_, clientx0_.LOGIN as LOGIN9_4_, clientx0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD10_4_, clientx0_.STATUT as STATUT13_4_ from CLIENT clientx0_ where clientx0_.PASSWORD=? and clientx0_.LOGIN=?

When I execute manually the SQL query on the database, it takes only 3ms :

```
select * from CLIENT where PASSWORD='xxxxx' and LOGIN='yyyyyyyy'
```

We have 4000 clients in our development environnement. More than a million in production.

Here the context :

- JDK 8
- Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE + JPA + Hibernate
- Oracle Database 10

Any idea ?

Comment: What is `CustomAuditable<Long>`?  Is it expensive to create a `Client` instance?

Comment: have you tried measuring the transaction execution time on the application side?

Comment: Could you post the actual sql produced by hibernate? Probably you have some eagerloading or other subsequent queries running. Hibernate statistics can also shpw you the actual query execution times.

Comment: I have updated the post with the Hibernate query and have deleted the CustomAuditable (useless in this context and I dont want to detail how it is working to not overload the post - the results are the same).
And why I should take measures on the application side ? It is slow on the DAO side.

Comment: Can you add a index for password, login combination. It may improve the query performance.

Comment: @Sudhakar : yes already done :)

Answer (score 3):

I have tested different types of DAO (I don't publish code here because it is so dirty) :

- **With Hibernate** : ~200ms
- **With (Injected) Spring JDBCTemplate and RowMapper** : ~70 ms
- **With Java Statement** : ~2 ms
- **With Java OracleStatement** : ~5 ms
- **With Java PreparedStatement** : ~100ms
- **With Java PreparedStatement adjusted with Fetch size = 5000** : ~50ms
- **With Java OraclePreparedStatement** : ~100ms
- **With Java OraclePreparedStatement adjusted with PreFetch size** = 5000 : ~170ms

*Notes :*

- DAO injected by Spring instead of *new ClientDao()* : +30ms lost (-sick-)
- Connection time to DB : 46ms

I could use :

- Java Statement with manual sanitized fields.
- Pre-connection on application launch
- Do not use Spring Injection

But :

- Not really secured / safe
- Fast for a small number of rows, slow to map ResultSet to entity on large number of rows (I also have this use case)

**So :**

The **Spring JDBCTemplate** with **RowMapper** seems to be the best solution to increase performances on specific case.
And we can keep a security on SQL queries.
But need to write specific RowMapper to transform ResultSet to Entity.

Example of Spring JDBCTemplate

```
@Repository
public class ClientJdbcTemplateDao {


    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientJdbcTemplateDao.class);

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Client> find() {
        List<Client> c = this.jdbcTemplate.query( "SELECT login FROM Client WHERE LOGIN='xxxx' AND PASSWORD='xxx'", new ClientRowMapper());
        return c;
    }
}
```

Example of Client RowMapper

```
public class ClientRowMapper implements RowMapper<Client> {

    @Override
    public Client mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        // HERE IMPLEMENTS THE CONVERTER
        // Sample : 
        // String login = arg0.getString("LOGIN")
        // Client client = new Client(login);
        // return client;
    }
}
```

Maybe can be better, any suggestion is welcome.