# Spring Data JPA: very slow insert and select queries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a pretty simple spring-data-jpa + Hibernate application, which stores customers data in MySql Database (the full source code is posted [here](https://gist.github.com/grelaxus/4b15abbeb39feeb670c77ce760121baa)).

The problem is that it runs *insert* and *select* queries **very slowly**, comparing to what I have through mysql CLI:

- insert one row takes ~**3600ms**,
- select all (just 2 rows) takes ~**1700ms**
- both queries take in mysql CLI about **0.12s**.

There is a similar problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313033/spring-jpa-hibernate-slow-select-query), however in my case the measurements are way worse (even though I don't insert batch, it's just one simple row in DB). Is there any way to improve performance in Spring JPA/Hibernate?

Another question, is there any way to reduce size of spring-data-jpa and hibernate-entitymanager? I was able to exclude byte-buddy and jandex dependencies without harm to the program, but that's only couple Mbs (the shaded jar size is down from 19.6Mb to 16.6Mb)?

**UPDATE**
As per request here is the code (the all sources are [here](https://gist.github.com/grelaxus/4b15abbeb39feeb670c77ce760121baa)):

```
@Entity
@AttributeAccessor("field")
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id",unique=true, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
  @Type(type="long")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
//+ constructors, getters/setters
}
```

Here is Spring application and also saving (insert) customer:

```
public class Application {
  private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  static CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MySQLAutoconfiguration.class);

    customerRepository = ctx.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);
    runTest();
  }

private static void runTest () throws {
...
//insert
  Customer customerJohn = customerRepository.save(new Customer("John"));
//select
  Customer foundEntity = customerRepository.findOne(customerJohn.getId());
...
}
```

And configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = "com.vk.dal.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:mysql.properties")
public class MySQLAutoconfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username") != null ? env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username") : "");
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password") != null ? env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password") : "");

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.vk.dal.domain");
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    Properties properties = additionalProperties();
    if (properties != null) {
      em.setJpaProperties(properties);
    }
    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
  }


  final Properties additionalProperties() {
    final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("mysql-hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("mysql-hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("mysql-hibernate.show_sql") != null ? env.getProperty("mysql-hibernate.show_sql") : "false");

    return hibernateProperties;
  }

}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you add some code like entity which you are using and how you are persisting anf fetching data ....

Comment: first action on so big framework takes extensive class loading, warming up etc. Maybe save() hides this problem and time is incorrect?

Comment: @Ashish451 added

Comment: @JacekCz, I guess that I run save() after Spring is loaded. Anyways, this is true that Spring\Hibernate are quite heavy, but the extent of degradation is too bad: over 3s per one record insert, almost 2s per select - that's way too much. No production would endure that.

Comment: realistic test such libraries is done without measure (out of ranking) few operations, and timing the next. Almost all is 'heavy', auto scanning of entities and more ...

Comment: I have something similar happening to me. Could you find a solution?

Comment: Do you really need `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"`?

Comment: Hey @VicK did you find a workaround or a solution for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hey anybody find a solution to this? Im facing similar issue